# Не могу получить доступ к элементам объектов в двумерном массиве

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Есть трёхмерный массив с объектами, внутри которых находятся нужные мне значения. Нужно перебрать/проверить несколько значений, и на основе этих данных собрать двумерный массив, состоящий из нулей и единиц. Во время перебора у первоначального массива все значения видны как ноль. Если при каждой итерации выводить в консоль объект, то половина переменных нулевые, но если раскрыть каждый (кликнуть на него), то все показывает правильно.

Примерный код:

```
this.getG = function() {
    var grid = [];
    var i = 0;
    //this.Area 2х мерный массив объектов Heap
    for(var y = 0; y < this.Area[i].length; y++) {
       grid[y] = [];
       for(var x = 0; x < this.Area[i][y].length; x++) {
          if(this.Area[i][y][x].ent > 0 || this.Area[i][y][x].flr < 0) {
             //Сюда не заходит с этими условиями
             grid[y][x] = 1;
             //все проверяемые значения нулевые (но это не так) если вывести:
             console.log(this.Area[i][y][x]); //Выведет Heap> {obj:0, obj2:0}
             //Но если раскрыть это то все значения на месте
          } else grid[y][x] = 0;
       }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Как мне добраться до нужных мне значений? Условия проверки схематичны.

P.S. В других браузерах тоже самое.

P.P.S. Что я уже ни пробовал: и делал это массив двумерным, и глобальным, и убирал наследования для класса `Heap`. В этот массив можно везде загнать любое значение и тут же прочитать, но в другой функции оно все равно будет ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в асинхронности. Так уж получилось что ожидаемый json возвращается позже исполнения всего (пока что) написанного кода.